# AWS Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest' with Evaporate.js

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using the Evaporate (https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS) to upload my files to S3. The app is in Vue/Nuxt.js setup, and this is my config:

```
const uploadApiConfig = {
    signerUrl: '/api/sign_auth',
    awsRegion: process.env.awsRegion,
    aws_key: process.env.awsKey,
    bucket: process.env.awsBucket,
    computeContentMd5: true,
    awsSignatureVersion: '4',
    cryptoMd5Method: (data) => {
        return AWS.util.crypto.md5(data, 'base64')
    },
    cryptoHexEncodedHash256: (data) => {
        return AWS.util.crypto.sha256(data, 'hex')
    },
    signHeaders: {
        'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
}
```

but still get this error `Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=.../s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date` Anyone can help?

Comment: The problem was with API url. It's fine now.